# Transcend SD card recognized as SanDisk card

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, htc, htc-one, google-photos

Recently I bought a [Transcend SD card (32 GB)](https://www.transcend-info.com/products/Product_detail.aspx?no=320) for my HTC One E8 dual sim, but Android recognized it as SanDisk card.

Besides, I noticed that in Google Photos it sometimes takes too long to move photos to trash (about 5 sec). Is this normal behavior?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting about make being wrongly recognised.  Google photos deletion does take the time you described for me

Comment: This suggests a way to reduce time https://support.google.com/photos/forum/AAAAzDQC9KEa-m34t1dSl4/?hl=en